# arcgis 10.2 how to order query results

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, order

is there a way to order the returned results of a query task?

this:

```
query.where = "COD > 0";
```

works fine, but this:

```
query.where = "COD > 0 order by COD";
```

throws:

```
dojo.io.script error undefined
```

Please note that our server has standardized queries enabled and we cannot change that.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause parameter is *ONLY* a WHERE clause.  You can specify a data source based on an ORDER BY (view or Query Layer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vince is right.

in the jsapi this is expressed as query.orderByFields
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#orderbyfields

in REST itself, the parameter is the same:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Feature_Service_Layer/02r3000000r1000000/